# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'talepID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to do the listing according to the id parameter. In a href I have defined the onClick property modal and I need to get id info. Although I make the route config settings, I see that the variable value is null and the controller is not running.

How can I make this system work?

Error:

GET http://localhost:4120/Application/TalepDetay/5 500 (Internal Server Error)

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TalepDetay(int talepID)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Javascript:

> $(\'#modalLg\').modal({ backdrop: \'static\', keyboard: true
>   }).find(\'#modal-contents
>   lg\').html(\'\').load(\'**/Application/TalepDetay/'+row.talepID**+'\');

RouteConfig:

defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },

Answer (score 0):

You should change it;

```
http://localhost:4120/Application/TalepDetay/5
```

to

```
http://localhost:4120/Application/TalepDetay?talepID=5
```

or you can set `Route` parameter;

```
[Route("application/TalepDetay/{talepID}")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TalepDetay(int talepID)
```